# Can't get mysql query to work with double or single qoute

Tags: php, mysql

I am scratching my head to make this lines of code to work, but no success...Would be nice if someone can point out what is the best practice to write such queries?

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["id"] > 0)
{
    include('../../config.php');            

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["desc"]);        

    $cat = $_POST["catid"];

    $_DB->Execute("UPDATE gallery_imgs SET title = `$title`, description = `$desc` WHERE id = $id");

    header("location: admin.php?mode=images&id=$cat");
}
else
{
     //Other stuff!
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error number: 1054
Error       : Unknown column 'The SIEK!' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have called `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the string values, but you must also validate the contents of `$_POST['id']`.

```
// invalid string values will convert to integer 0
// If that is not allowable, you should not proceed with the query.
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

Input strings must be enclosed in single quotes, not backquotes (which are used for column and table identifiers);

```
$_DB->Execute("UPDATE gallery_imgs SET title = '$title', description = '$desc' WHERE id = $id");
```

As an aside, you should validate the contents of `$_POST['catid']` before using it in a redirection header.  For example, if it is supposed to be numeric:

```
// At least cast it to an int if it is an invalid string....
$catid = intval($_POST['catid']);
```

Comment: What happens if $title is "`Don't look now!`".  Oops.  Surely you should have at least mentioned `mysql_escape_string()` !!

Comment: @TerryE The OP has already called `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the title and description. See the original post above...

Comment: @Michael, Ooops!  I guess that I should RTFQ :LoL:

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't single quotes you are using there.  the tick mark ` is for column names.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL uses single quotes wrapping strings. Like this: '.

```
$_DB->Execute("UPDATE gallery_imgs SET title = '$title', description = '$desc' WHERE id = $id");
```

You should also look at validating the $id. (Using is_numeric() or casting to int).

Tip: For a more robust and secure MySQL solution you should look at PHP PDO.